# Sharepoint Online restrict subsite creation

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am trying to restrict users to create subsites but with manage permissions.

Essentially I created a new perm level without subsites creation which works flawlessly unless someone amends the permissions level and enable Full Control and then they are able to create subsites.

If I take away Manage permissions then those users are unable to manage permissions on list/library level and this becomes problematic.

I was wondering if there us a way to restrict subsite creation without taking away manage permissions on site level.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can disable this from the Admin Centre

1. Admin centers > SharePoint.
2. Click settings.
3. Under Site creation, select Hide the Create site command or Show the Create site command to users who have permission to create sites.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-site-creation-in-SharePoint-Online-e72844a3-0171-47c9-befb-e98b23e2dcf9

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for. Does it work in Modern and Classic experiences? cheers

Comment: @AsadRajput If it was a classic site previously, you can change to classic experience and create subsites.  Sites created as modern doesn't allow you to switch back to classic.